# How do I modify a stored procedure in IBM DB2?

Tags: db2, db2-9.7

I have a DB2 database and I'm using Control Center. I've found a procedure in the 'Stored Procedures' folder, which I need to modify. In MS SQL Server and Oracle you can accomplish this right from the DBMS.

Is there a way I can modify this procedure with an editor in DB2 (9.7.0), similar to SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: I believe you can do so through IBM Data Studio. I would use that tool anyway as that is now the approved IBM tool for interacting with DB2 and Control Center is deprecated.

Comment: If by "right from the DBMS" you mean "from within a GUI designed for administering the database", then yes Data Studio is the currently approved tool for this. There used to be a GUI tool shipped with control center (which as Chris correctly points out is deprecated) which permitted development of stored procs but I can't even remember its name (I only ever used vi and the command line for this!)

Comment: @ChrisAldrich Please post this as an answer, because IBM Data Studio worked out for me and I was able to accomplish what I needed to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do so through IBM Data Studio. I would use that tool anyway as that is now the approved IBM tool for interacting with DB2 and Control Center is deprecated.